# Excel lookups - different parts of an array

Tags: arrays, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet that has various dropdowns. I would like to use the vlookup function elsewhere in the spreadsheet to provide data from different parts of the same array depending on the result of the dropdown. Anyone able to help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your drop down must point to the correct row and column index in the array. You could try a dropdown that identifies the the column number and another that identifies the key in the first column of the array to return the row. Please clarify your question with an example if you'd like a more coherent answer.